# Handling backpressure data tranmission in mqtt client

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, messagebroker

We have a mosquito broker installed in our cloud server. Our gateway is sending data by using an MQTT client with 2G signal. We are observing data loss in a few scenarios.

When the gateway is disconnected from internet we queue messages in the gateway for few days. When it reaches the internet again then it starts pushing data to broker with two threads: one is for live messages, the other is for queued messages. We get a callback ACK for each and every message but we are loosing some messages on the server side.

1. **How do we make sure that all produced messages will be processed in the broker?**
2. **How do we handle the burst of message in the gateway?** One option is to delay the sending of each queued message by a few milliseconds (to avoid that they all try to reach the broker at once.

We are using QoS level 1 for our publisher/subscriber and want to continued using QoS level 1.

Comment: Not knowing the payload size of the messages you might want to check whether "a few milliseconds" are enough to overcome the 2G limitations of roughly 40kbit/s. You might have to spread it out even further.

Comment: Based on the number of parameter our pay load size will increase.In our current each payload size around 200 byte.But What we are suspecting at a time queued 1000 packet we trying to send. This case 200 kb we are sending will it be queued until reaches broker?

Comment: @kannadhasan , were you able to figure out the reason or a possible solution to the issue.